# Posición de funciones en AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

tengo una duda y tal vez me gustaría saber que me recomiendan ubicar el código siguiente, son `2` funciones la pregunta es cual de las dos va primero al cargar el archivo `js`?

```
$scope.firstFunction = function() {
  $scope.algo = true;
  $scope.ffaff = "";
  secondFunction();
}

function secondFunction() {
 $scope.pold = false;
 $scope.fafa = {};
}
```

En posición de código cual de las dos debe ir primero cuando se ejecute el archivo `js`, como pueden ver la función `firstFunction` ejecuta la función `secondFunction()`?

Comment: No creo que el orden tenga haga mucha diferencia. A menos que ejecutes la funcion `firstFuncion()` antes de declarar la funcion `secondFuncion()`.

Comment: @Einer pero entonces así esta bien su orden?

Comment: En cuanto a flujo del programa si.